# Java Lambda Expressions and Object Method Reference

Tags: java, function, lambda, reference

I am currently working on a Java project which will use lambda expressions to update information directly.  In this code, Item o will use two lambda expressions, which the object will call at the appropriate time to make calculations.  I am using lambda expressions so that I can define a custom function for each item (and would rather not use anonymous objects).

I am running into a problem where I need the lambda function to get information from the object which is executing it (o, in this case).  I cannot compile because inside of the function, o.getObjectWidth(), the IDE tells me that 'o may not have been initialized' (which is technically true at this point).

Is there a different way I can include the reference in the lambda expression?

```
private void addAllItems() {
    Color shipColor = Color.GRAY;
    //draw the bottom oval
    int width = 100;
    int height = 90;
    Item o = new Item("bov","oval",10,true,shipColor,true,Color.black,
            new int[] {0,60,width,height},new int[] {0,0,1,1},
            (Function<Integer,Integer>[]) new Function[]{
                //update by keyboard x
                (n) -> {
                    return DynamicInfo.getKeyboardX()+o.getObjectWidth()/2;
                },
                (n)-> {
                    return DynamicInfo.getKeyboardY()+o.getObjectHeight()/2;
                },
                null,
                null
    });

    allItems.addItem(o);
}
```

Comment: Redesign your class to take lambdas with two arguments, so it passes both `n` _and_ `o` into calls to the lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest approach is to pass `Item` directly to the function itself along with `Integer` parameter.

Use `BiFunction`:

```
BiFunction<Item, Integer, Integer>
```

The lambda will look like this:

```
(i, n) -> {
    return DynamicInfo.getKeyboardX()+i.getObjectWidth()/2;
},
(i, n)-> {
    return DynamicInfo.getKeyboardX()+i.getObjectWidth()/2;
}
```

And pass reference to itself when calling the function inside the `Item`:

```
f.apply(this, 4)
```

BTW, why not use List and avoid the ugly cast when creating the array:

```
Item(...., List< BiFunction<Item, Integer, Integer> > functions, ...)

new Item( ..., Arrays.asList( 
        (i, n) -> {
            return DynamicInfo.getKeyboardX()+i.getObjectWidth()/2;
        },
        (i, n)-> {
            return DynamicInfo.getKeyboardX()+i.getObjectWidth()/2;
        } ), .... );
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is much more elegant and solves the problem!